# Custom Validator, Validation Summary (Asp.Net, Vb.Net WebForms)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

My page has multiple validations, but also have multiple buttons. On a particular button [Submit], I don't need to call all the validations, I just need a particular validation where the input from the user, will be validated when it's already in the database or not. If not, an error message will be displayed. Is there a way, that I don't have to go through all the validations when method [Page.Validate()] or is there a way to call a particular validation only?

My markup:

```
 <Asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtReference" MaxLength="1" autocomplete="off" />
 <Asp:CustomValidator ID="cvReference"
       runat="server"                 
       ValidationGroup="vgReferenceErrors"
       ControlToValidate="txtReference"/>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="btnSubmit"/>
 <Asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsReferenceErrors"
         runat="server"
         EnableClientScript="True"
         ValidationGroup="vgReferenceErrors" />
```

Code Behind:

```
 Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Page.Validate()
        If (Page.IsValid) Then

        End If
 End Sub



Private Sub cvReference_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles cvReference.ServerValidate
    
    Dim isReferenceExists As Boolean = False

    Try
       
                isReferenceExists = VerifyReference(txtReference.Text)
                args.IsValid = Not isReferenceExists 

    Catch ex As Exception
        
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`Button.ValidationGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup?view=netframework-4.8.1) property in order to sets the group of controls for which the Button control causes validation when it posts back to the server.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="btnSubmit" ValidationGroup="vgReferenceErrors" />
```

Comment: Should I set the autopostback to true as well?

Comment: Button doesn't have AutoPostBack property; verify that CausesValidation is set to True (default value). I don't think you need to force page validation in btnSubmit_Click if you set Button.ValidationGroup.